# Multi Query / Multi Sort (?) with Mongoose in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose

I've been working on a news site where users can post articles and leave comments. Part of the comments is to designate an emotion to the comment (one of 5 options: Amazed, Happy, Neutral, Sad, Angry).

What i want to do with this is make a 'top 5' of articles with the highest emotion count for a specific emotion. And sure, i know on a forum the emotion is always 'angry' so i should just work with that ;D , but this is part of a learning experience and i'd like to know how to do this.

So for other top5's ( 'hot discussion' and 'hot news' ) i have introduced counters in my Article Schema, that get incremented either when a comment is made (for 'hotDiscussion'), or when a user designates something as truly 'hot news' ( 'like button functionality' ). Then i simply search for the Articles and sort by these counters...

BUT, for this specific case, where there are 5 options, how do i sort ?!? ... at first i thought i would just implement the counters when a certain emotion is picked (pull down menu). But then all the counters are 'on the Article' as a single entity and i don't see how you would sort by all of them to get a comprehensive list. So then i though to put them in an object or array... something like:

```
Article {
   title: String,
   author: user...
   comments: []
   emotions: [ or {
        Amazed: amazedCount,
        Happy: happyCount,
        Neutral: neutralCount,
        Sad: sadCount,
        Angry: angryCount
   } or ]
```

Then, maybe i can find all the articles and sort by emotions (somehow?) and then skim off the top 5 from the list. But here again i run into the 5 options thing. And i have no clue how to sort the emotions? to then perhaps within the results, sort by the first (highest) count. To then skim of the top5.

So looking around here somewhat hints at me going for something like this

```
Article {
   ...
   ...
   emotions: [ 
       {name: Amazed, value: amazedCount},
       {name: Happy, value: happyCount},
       {name: Neutral, value: neutralCount},
       {name: Sad, value: sadCount},
       {name: Angry, value: angryCount}
     ]
```

And i like this direction somewhat, due to the **clear keys** 'name' & 'value'.
But here i run into the same issue, aka. lack of knowledge ... Because:

- how to sort on a second order value, as i would be sorting on value?
- will the same article just show up multiple times in the result? (i'dd like to prevent that if at all possible, a very busy mixed emotion thread should not show up twice over a less busy but clearly 'happy' thread in the top5 ).

So hopefully somebody can help me, as i can see this type of searching valuable in various types of situations, not just for some learning environment type 'forum' top5.

---

For those needing a more useful 'use case'

```
warehouse{
   name: String,
   ... : ...
   parts: [
        {name: part1, value: Count}
        {name: part2, value: Count}
        {etc }
         ]
    }
```

Generating a list of warehouses based upon the count of parts (where double mention of a certain warehouse isn't a problem); Or say a list of Car Dealers with the highest count for available brands or models (to get input for redistribution f/e). Or a list of online shops with a multi value rating system (f/e: delivery speed, customer service, price of products, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out this is actually fairly simple ... as i was most the way there. Just needed to put the sort criteria in between '...'  /doh !

***!* THIS CODE IS NOT COMPLETE**, as in Copy/Paste you are done, but the Code below does show you most the places where you need to 'do' things to make this work (/show routes not included, aka the pages the user sees and can input stuff on)

```
    // In the Schemas:
        Article {
           ...
           ...
           emotions: [ {emotion: String, eCount: Number} ]
        }

        Comment{
           emotion: String;  //to save the emotion of the user on the comment
         }
    
    // Upon initializing an Article:
        router.post("/route", function(req, res){
            let etcetera: etc,
            let theEmotions = [  // in your usecase you may populate these elsewhere
                            { emotion: "Amazed", eCount: 0 }, 
                            { emotion: "Happy", eCount: 0 }, 
                            { emotion: "Neutral", eCount: 0 },
                            { emotion: "Sad", eCount: 0 },
                            { emotion: "Angry", eCount: 0 }     
                        ];
        
            let newArticle = {
              etc: etc,
              emotions: theEmotions
            };
        
            Article.create(newArticle, function(err, newArticle){
               *stuff here*
            });
        });
        
    // when a comment gets made, it updates the scores based upon the emotion selected
    //REST :: CREATE --> actually creates a new comment
    router.post("/", function(req, res){
        Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundArticle){
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR @ finding article to POST the COMMENT");
                res.redirect('/articles');
            } else {
                Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, createdComment){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("ERROR @ CREATing new COMMENT");
                    } else {
                        switch(createdComment.emotion){
                            case "Amazed":
                                foundArticle.emotions[0].eCount += 1;
                                break;
                            case "Happy":
                                foundArticle.emotions[1].eCount += 1;
                                break;
                            case "Neutral":
                                foundArticle.emotions[2].eCount += 1;
                                break;
                            case "Sad":
                                foundArticle.emotions[3].eCount += 1;
                                break;
                            case "Angry":
                                foundArticle.emotions[4].eCount += 1;
                                break;
                            default:
                                console.log("ERROR @ Emotion Switch in comments route");
                        }
                        //add username and id to comment
                        createdComment.user.id = req.user._id;
                        createdComment.user.username = req.user.username;
                        createdComment.save();
                        foundArticle.comments.push(createdComment);
                        foundArticle.save();
                        console.log("SUCCESS @ CREATing new COMMENT");
                        res.redirect('/articles/' + foundArticle._id);
                    }       
                });
            }
        });
    });

    //Where one wants to sort: ... note the '...' around 'emotions.eCount'
    router.get("/specificRoute, function(req, res){
        Article.find({}).sort({'emotions.eCount': -1}).exec(function(err, hotEmotions){
    
            *stuff happens here*
    
        });
    });
```

Hopefully this will be of some help to someone somewhere in the future :)